# Is there a list of reserved FlashVars names?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flashvars, reserved-words

Currently I work on localization for a Flex application. From [an article](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_3:Feature_Introductions:_Runtime_Localization) I know that you can control the localization with the following FlashVars:

- resourceModuleURLs
- localeChain

Are there any other FlashVars reserved by Adobe that a Flash/Flex Developer should know about?

Answer (score 1):

I recently was playing with [ContextMenuItem](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html) and found a list of words that cannot be used for a caption or label in a [ContextMenuItem](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html). Not sure if it helps.

Save
 Zoom In
 Zoom Out
 100%
 Show All
 Quality
 Play
 Loop
 Rewind
 Forward
 Back
 Movie not loaded
 About
 Print
 Show Redraw Regions
 Debugger
 Undo
 Cut
 Copy
 Paste
 Delete
 Select All
 Open
 Open in new window
 Copy link
 Adobe
 Macromedia
 Flash Player
 Settings

Also a hack was suggested [here](http://www.themorphicgroup.com/blog/2009/07/06/contextmenu-copy-paste-delete/), although I never tried it personally.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was asking about but a similar problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.nbilyk.com/flex-localization-example) has a fairly easy tutorial. The conversation in the comments will cover a few best practices for you as well.

Here is an adobe [livedoc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_2.html) on runtime localization that you may not have seen yet either.

This final [link](http://bugs.adobe.com/confluence/display/ADOBE/Flex+3+Details+-+Runtime+Localization) provides an update on the changes in the localization API made in Flex 3 and documents the deprecated and new classes/methods, etc. (a list with examples is at the bottom of the document).

On a side note if anyone is looking for a tool to help out with translations David Deraedt wrote some nice air apps called [Lupo Localization Studio](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/88) that are reasonably inexpensive.

Comment: I was actually asking about other FlashVars names reserved by Adobe. Localization how-tos are helpful but do not answer the question.